# What does "when nine and nine meet nine" mean?

Tags: final-fantasy

in *Final Fantasy Type-0* in The Nameless Tome 14:7 it says

> "I will become Agito. I will sound the knell to shake all the world. 
>       When nine and nine meet nine, the depths of reason shall stir. 
>       When the seal of creation is broken, a voice like thunder shall sound, 
>  
>       And thou shalt know—we have arrived"

I get the part about Agito sounding the knell to shake all the world relates to how

> if the Agito is found Tempus Finis is stopped and the fal'Cie have someone to find the gateway to the unseen realm

Seal of Creation is to do with the Balance of the 4 Crystals and the Voice like thunder is the voice of the Rursus.

But the part i don't really understand is what it means by *"When nine and nine meet nine, the depths of reason shall stir."*. what exactly does nine and nine meet nine refer too?

Comment: it's like super easy, Level 99 Nine is THE Agito

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the explanation given by Hiroki Chiba (Scenario Writer) for the phrase:

> The number "9" is the last single-digit number so it symbolizes the
>   “end”. The phrase is a unique abstract mythological expression which
>   means the end of 3 signifies the end of the world (collapse of the
>   cycle of death and rebirth). The unification of Orience, the end of 3
>   countries, is one of the things that 9 and 9 and 9 implies.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/FinalFantasy/comments/30jj0e/ff_type0_ending_explained_heavy_spoilers/)